# case insensitive inArray for Zend Form elements like Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox and so on

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

By default, some form elements (such as Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox
 and so on) register an InArray validator which validates against the array keys of registered options. This validator used case sensitive compaision. What is the simplest what to make case insensitive? 
The only solution that occurs to me now looks something like this.
Turn off this validator:

```
$element->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);
```

Create new validator that will make case insensitive comparision and add this validation for the element. Is this the only way to solve this problem? It seems it would be nice if there is a standard way to make inArray validator to make case insensitive comparision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Zend_Validate_InArray` uses `in_array` function, and the documentation for the function says:

> If needle is a string, the comparison is done in a case-sensitive manner.

`Zend_Validate_InArray` includes option for strict comparison, which is in turn handled by `in_array` function, too. But there is no option for case-insensitive comparison.

With `resursive` option, `Zend_Validate_InArray` makes use of recursive iterators instead of `in_array` and compares the values by means of `==` (or, in strict mode, `===`) operator. Which is case-sensitive, too.

So there is no other option but to create your own validator (which I would inherit from `Zend_Validate_InArray`, overriding `public function isValid($value)`).

Comment: Yes, I read documentation. But it seemed strange to me that there is not such standard validator in Zend Framework.